# To Update fields on Case from email Body on Email to Case functionality?

Tags: apex-email-service, email2case

We have a set up On Demand Email to Case in our org. The customer send some information in the email body and i need to parse the email body to get the information for the fields and populate it on the case record.Can someone help me in resolving this.

Thanks ,
Sana Tarique

Answer (score 3):

I think your best option might be to set up a trigger in the `Case` object so everytime a case is inserted from the Email2Case service you can parse the body and populate the required fields as you wish.

If you have really complex business logic, you can always go for a specific `InboundEmailHandler`, but I'm not sure that you really need this option.

Comment: I have utilized InboundEmailHandler functionality of salesforce.

Comment: @NITHESHK cool. If you found that the answer was sufficient for your question, feel free to accept it :)

Comment: Yes i did already.